# Permission Issues in IIS Server Hosting

Tags: asp.net-web-api, file-permissions

I have a web api project which has a folder called as "Resources" and it primarily contains only html files and "cer" files.

If I give the folder the everyone permission, i am able to read the files from the code, else we get the UnAuthorizedAccess exception.

Any insights will be very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C#, the FileAccess is to be set in the FileStream as shown below

```
FileStream(String, FileMode, FileAccess)
```

This fixes the above issue